# Vote to reject edit show up in approved list

Tags: bug, moderation, editing, voting

In the [Suggested Edits page of the Moderator tools](https://music.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits), I noticed that my name appeared in the "approved by" list for an edit I voted to reject. (See image below.)

This seems like a bug, either in that my name should not have been included, or the "approved by" label should be something like "voted on by"

Allowing this might be SE-wide behavior, but starting here in case it's specific to MP&T.

---

[image: Image of "approved by" list]

---

Answer (score 1):

When I click through to see the edit, and then click through *again* to see the review details, it *does* show that you voted to reject:

[image: image of edit review]

I don't have moderator tools to show the image in your question.
But, I agree that it is silly that rejectors would be grouped in the list that approved. This should be fixed.

PS: I don't know why someone hiding under the "Community Bot" alias was able to make *that* edit. I would I have also denied it based on the reasons you gave.
(I'd do a rollback myself, but I feel this would undermine the review process.)

Comment: Yeah, the behavior seems specific to the moderation tool; the main queue is fine, as you show. Agreed that a rollback would be inappropriate in this case.